# Merge several arrays/objects returned in several ways

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have created a select that on change extracts "nodes" and "links" from an object. After I change the value I have to recreate the object with the same structure as `jsonServit` but with the new content resulted.

In the code below I have 3 console.log's. I have to mix those 3 returns into a single object. If i select the first value of the select i get:

- first console log (SelectedNodeArray):

```
//should be grouped with "nodes"
{id: "Anzelma", group: 4}
```

- second console log (LinksArray):

```
//should be grouped with "links"
0: {source: "Anzelma", target: "Eponine", value: 2}
1: {source: "Anzelma", target: "Thenardier", value: 2}
2: {source: "Anzelma", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 1}
```

- third console log (linkedNodesArray) inside the for loop:

```
//should be grouped with "nodes"
0: {id: "Eponine", group: 4}
0: {id: "Thenardier", group: 4}
0: {id: "Mme.Thenardier", group: 4}
```

How can i combine all the 3 returns into an object like this?

```
{"nodes":[
    {id: "Anzelma", group: 4},
    {id: "Eponine", group: 4},
    {id: "Thenardier", group: 4},
    {id: "Mme.Thenardier", group: 4}
],
"links":[
    {source: "Anzelma", target: "Eponine", value: 2},
    {source: "Anzelma", target: "Thenardier", value: 2},
    {source: "Anzelma", target: "Mme.Thenardier", value: 1}
]}
```

Thank you.

```js
let jsonServit = {"nodes":[{"id":"Myriel","group":1},{"id":"Napoleon","group":1,"type":"person"},{"id":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},{"id":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},{"id":"CountessdeLo","group":1},{"id":"Geborand","group":1},{"id":"Champtercier","group":1},{"id":"Cravatte","group":1},{"id":"Count","group":1},{"id":"OldMan","group":1},{"id":"Labarre","group":2},{"id":"Valjean","group":2},{"id":"Marguerite","group":3},{"id":"Mme.deR","group":2},{"id":"Isabeau","group":2},{"id":"Gervais","group":2},{"id":"Tholomyes","group":3},{"id":"Listolier","group":3},{"id":"Fameuil","group":3},{"id":"Blacheville","group":3},{"id":"Favourite","group":3},{"id":"Dahlia","group":3},{"id":"Zephine","group":3},{"id":"Fantine","group":3},{"id":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},{"id":"Thenardier","group":4},{"id":"Cosette","group":5},{"id":"Javert","group":4},{"id":"Fauchelevent","group":0},{"id":"Bamatabois","group":2},{"id":"Perpetue","group":3},{"id":"Simplice","group":2},{"id":"Scaufflaire","group":2},{"id":"Woman1","group":2},{"id":"Judge","group":2},{"id":"Champmathieu","group":2},{"id":"Brevet","group":2},{"id":"Chenildieu","group":2},{"id":"Cochepaille","group":2},{"id":"Pontmercy","group":4},{"id":"Boulatruelle","group":6},{"id":"Eponine","group":4},{"id":"Anzelma","group":4},{"id":"Woman2","group":5},{"id":"MotherInnocent","group":0},{"id":"Gribier","group":0},{"id":"Jondrette","group":7},{"id":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},{"id":"Gavroche","group":8},{"id":"Gillenormand","group":5},{"id":"Magnon","group":5},{"id":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},{"id":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},{"id":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},{"id":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},{"id":"Marius","group":8},{"id":"BaronessT","group":5},{"id":"Mabeuf","group":8},{"id":"Enjolras","group":8},{"id":"Combeferre","group":8},{"id":"Prouvaire","group":8},{"id":"Feuilly","group":8},{"id":"Courfeyrac","group":8},{"id":"Bahorel","group":8},{"id":"Bossuet","group":8},{"id":"Joly","group":8},{"id":"Grantaire","group":8},{"id":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},{"id":"Gueulemer","group":4},{"id":"Babet","group":4},{"id":"Claquesous","group":4},{"id":"Montparnasse","group":4},{"id":"Toussaint","group":5},{"id":"Child1","group":10},{"id":"Child2","group":10},{"id":"Brujon","group":4},{"id":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}],
       "links":[{"source":"Napoleon","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Baptistine","target":"Myriel","value":8},{"source":"Mme.Magloire","target":"Myriel","value":10},{"source":"Mme.Magloire","target":"Mlle.Baptistine","value":6},{"source":"CountessdeLo","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Geborand","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Champtercier","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Cravatte","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Count","target":"Myriel","value":2},{"source":"OldMan","target":"Myriel","value":1},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Labarre","value":1},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Mme.Magloire","value":3},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Mlle.Baptistine","value":3},{"source":"Valjean","target":"Myriel","value":5},{"source":"Marguerite","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Mme.deR","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Isabeau","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gervais","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Listolier","target":"Tholomyes","value":4},{"source":"Fameuil","target":"Tholomyes","value":4},{"source":"Fameuil","target":"Listolier","value":4},{"source":"Blacheville","target":"Tholomyes","value":4},{"source":"Blacheville","target":"Listolier","value":4},{"source":"Blacheville","target":"Fameuil","value":4},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Favourite","target":"Blacheville","value":4},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Blacheville","value":3},{"source":"Dahlia","target":"Favourite","value":5},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Blacheville","value":3},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Favourite","value":4},{"source":"Zephine","target":"Dahlia","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Tholomyes","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Listolier","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Fameuil","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Blacheville","value":3},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Favourite","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Dahlia","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Zephine","value":4},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Marguerite","value":2},{"source":"Fantine","target":"Valjean","value":9},{"source":"Mme.Thenardier","target":"Fantine","value":2},{"source":"Mme.Thenardier","target":"Valjean","value":7},{"source":"Thenardier","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":13},{"source":"Thenardier","target":"Fantine","value":1},{"source":"Thenardier","target":"Valjean","value":12},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":4},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Valjean","value":31},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Tholomyes","value":1},{"source":"Cosette","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Javert","target":"Valjean","value":17},{"source":"Javert","target":"Fantine","value":5},{"source":"Javert","target":"Thenardier","value":5},{"source":"Javert","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Javert","target":"Cosette","value":1},{"source":"Fauchelevent","target":"Valjean","value":8},{"source":"Fauchelevent","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Bamatabois","target":"Fantine","value":1},{"source":"Bamatabois","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Bamatabois","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Perpetue","target":"Fantine","value":1},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Perpetue","value":2},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Fantine","value":2},{"source":"Simplice","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Scaufflaire","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Woman1","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Woman1","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Judge","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Judge","target":"Bamatabois","value":2},{"source":"Champmathieu","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Champmathieu","target":"Judge","value":3},{"source":"Champmathieu","target":"Bamatabois","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Judge","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Champmathieu","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Brevet","target":"Bamatabois","value":1},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Judge","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Champmathieu","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Brevet","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Chenildieu","target":"Bamatabois","value":1},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Judge","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Champmathieu","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Brevet","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Chenildieu","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Cochepaille","target":"Bamatabois","value":1},{"source":"Pontmercy","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Boulatruelle","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Eponine","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":2},{"source":"Eponine","target":"Thenardier","value":3},{"source":"Anzelma","target":"Eponine","value":2},{"source":"Anzelma","target":"Thenardier","value":2},{"source":"Anzelma","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Woman2","target":"Valjean","value":3},{"source":"Woman2","target":"Cosette","value":1},{"source":"Woman2","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"MotherInnocent","target":"Fauchelevent","value":3},{"source":"MotherInnocent","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gribier","target":"Fauchelevent","value":2},{"source":"Mme.Burgon","target":"Jondrette","value":1},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Mme.Burgon","value":2},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Gavroche","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gillenormand","target":"Cosette","value":3},{"source":"Gillenormand","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Magnon","target":"Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Magnon","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Gillenormand","target":"Gillenormand","value":9},{"source":"Mlle.Gillenormand","target":"Cosette","value":2},{"source":"Mlle.Gillenormand","target":"Valjean","value":2},{"source":"Mme.Pontmercy","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Pontmercy","target":"Pontmercy","value":1},{"source":"Mlle.Vaubois","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Lt.Gillenormand","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":2},{"source":"Lt.Gillenormand","target":"Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Lt.Gillenormand","target":"Cosette","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Mlle.Gillenormand","value":6},{"source":"Marius","target":"Gillenormand","value":12},{"source":"Marius","target":"Pontmercy","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Lt.Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Cosette","value":21},{"source":"Marius","target":"Valjean","value":19},{"source":"Marius","target":"Tholomyes","value":1},{"source":"Marius","target":"Thenardier","value":2},{"source":"Marius","target":"Eponine","value":5},{"source":"Marius","target":"Gavroche","value":4},{"source":"BaronessT","target":"Gillenormand","value":1},{"source":"BaronessT","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Mabeuf","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Mabeuf","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Mabeuf","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Marius","value":7},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Gavroche","value":7},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Javert","value":6},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Enjolras","target":"Valjean","value":4},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Enjolras","value":15},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Marius","value":5},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Gavroche","value":6},{"source":"Combeferre","target":"Mabeuf","value":2},{"source":"Prouvaire","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Prouvaire","target":"Enjolras","value":4},{"source":"Prouvaire","target":"Combeferre","value":2},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Gavroche","value":2},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Enjolras","value":6},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Combeferre","value":5},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Feuilly","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Marius","value":9},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Enjolras","value":17},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Combeferre","value":13},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Gavroche","value":7},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Mabeuf","value":2},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Feuilly","value":6},{"source":"Courfeyrac","target":"Prouvaire","value":3},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Combeferre","value":5},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Gavroche","value":5},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Courfeyrac","value":6},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Mabeuf","value":2},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Enjolras","value":4},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Feuilly","value":3},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Bahorel","target":"Marius","value":1},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Marius","value":5},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Courfeyrac","value":12},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Gavroche","value":5},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Bahorel","value":4},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Enjolras","value":10},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Feuilly","value":6},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Combeferre","value":9},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Bossuet","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Joly","target":"Bahorel","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Bossuet","value":7},{"source":"Joly","target":"Gavroche","value":3},{"source":"Joly","target":"Courfeyrac","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Enjolras","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Feuilly","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Prouvaire","value":2},{"source":"Joly","target":"Combeferre","value":5},{"source":"Joly","target":"Mabeuf","value":1},{"source":"Joly","target":"Marius","value":2},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Bossuet","value":3},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Enjolras","value":3},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Combeferre","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Courfeyrac","value":2},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Joly","value":2},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Bahorel","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Feuilly","value":1},{"source":"Grantaire","target":"Prouvaire","value":1},{"source":"MotherPlutarch","target":"Mabeuf","value":3},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Thenardier","value":5},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Gueulemer","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Thenardier","value":6},{"source":"Babet","target":"Gueulemer","value":6},{"source":"Babet","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Javert","value":2},{"source":"Babet","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Babet","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Thenardier","value":4},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Babet","value":4},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Gueulemer","value":4},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Mme.Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Claquesous","target":"Enjolras","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Babet","value":2},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Gueulemer","value":2},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Claquesous","value":2},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Montparnasse","target":"Thenardier","value":1},{"source":"Toussaint","target":"Cosette","value":2},{"source":"Toussaint","target":"Javert","value":1},{"source":"Toussaint","target":"Valjean","value":1},{"source":"Child1","target":"Gavroche","value":2},{"source":"Child2","target":"Gavroche","value":2},{"source":"Child2","target":"Child1","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Babet","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Gueulemer","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Thenardier","value":3},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Eponine","value":1},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Claquesous","value":1},{"source":"Brujon","target":"Montparnasse","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Bossuet","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Joly","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Grantaire","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Bahorel","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Courfeyrac","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Gavroche","value":1},{"source":"Mme.Hucheloup","target":"Enjolras","value":1}]}


var namesArray = [];
var LinksArray = [];
var linkedNodesArray = [];

$.each(jsonServit.nodes, function(index) {
  var name = jsonServit.nodes[index].id;
  if ($.inArray(name, namesArray) == -1) {
    namesArray.push(name);
  }
});

namesArray.sort();

$.each(namesArray, function(index) {
  $("#SelectName").append('<option value="' + namesArray[index] + '">' + namesArray[index] + '</option>');
});

$("#SelectName").change(function() {
  var selectedName = this.value;

  SelectedNodeArray = $.grep(jsonServit.nodes, function(node, index) {
    return node.id == selectedName;
  });
  LinksArray = $.grep(jsonServit.links, function(link, index) {
    return link.source == selectedName;
  });

  console.log(SelectedNodeArray);
  console.log(LinksArray);

  for (var i = 0; i < LinksArray.length; i++) {
    linkedNodesArray = $.grep(jsonServit.nodes, function(link, index) {
      return link.id == LinksArray[i].target;
    });
    console.log(linkedNodesArray);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < linkedNodesArray.length; i++) {
    var linkedNodesArrayX = {"links":linkedNodesArray[i]};
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name:
<select id="SelectName">
  <option>Name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just FYI, this has nothing to do with JSON. What you have is an object containing arrays in its properties. JSON is a way of formatting data in to a string. They are two completely separate concepts. I've edited the question as such.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if I understand correctly the process goes as follow:

1. A list of unique character names is generated
2. A select is populated with the list
3. User selects one of these names
4. (Here you are missing a check that the selected name by the user also exists in your list as the user could generate anything)
5. The node corresponding to the select name is identified -> SelectedNodeArray
6. Related links are identified -> LinksArray
7. Nodes corresponding to the other side of the links are identified -> linkedNodesArray
8. Combine all 3 into an object with the same structure as what you originally got.

**Code**

```
var namesArray = [];

$.each(jsonServit.nodes, function(index) {
  var name = jsonServit.nodes[index].id;
  if ($.inArray(name, namesArray) == -1) {
    namesArray.push(name);
  }
});

namesArray.sort();

$.each(namesArray, function(index) {
  $("#SelectName").append('<option value="' + namesArray[index] + '">' + namesArray[index] + '</option>');
});

// result variable
var result = {};

$("#SelectName").change(function() {
  // Move the var declaration inside the each as they are temp variables
  var LinksArray = [];

  var selectedName = this.value;

  SelectedNodeArray = $.grep(jsonServit.nodes, function(node, index) {
    return node.id == selectedName;
  });
  LinksArray = $.grep(jsonServit.links, function(link, index) {
    return link.source == selectedName;
  });

  console.log(SelectedNodeArray);
  console.log(LinksArray);

  var linkedNodesArray = [].concat(SelectedNodeArray);

  for (var i = 0; i < LinksArray.length; i++) {
    linkedNodesArray = linkedNodesArray.concat($.grep(jsonServit.nodes, function(link, index) {
      return link.id == LinksArray[i].target;
    }));
  }
  console.log(linkedNodesArray);
  result.nodes = linkedNodesArray;
  result.links = LinksArray;

  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check soon.

Comment: Almost perfect, thank you. The only problem is that, if you look in console.log at result at "nodes" the current selected object appears as nodes[0][0] instead of nodes[0]. So the current selected object is inside another array in nodes array. A really good solution, otherwise. If you fix that the bounty is yours. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I totally missed that part. The thing should be fixed now :)

Comment: Wow, great. Thank you.